# Как делать задание по русскому языку

Tags: недопустимая-метка, школьное-задание

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите с заданием по русскому языку. Что за группы?

Answer (score 1):

Группы будут такими:

1. Имеется или подразумевается противопоставление с "не"
2. Слово без "не" не употребляется
3. Слово с "не" можно заменить синонимом без "не"

Comment: А какие предложения относятся к 3 пункту?

Comment: 1, 7 относятся туда.

Comment: Там ещё четвёртая есть.

Comment: Нет. Четвертая - это другое правило (подразумевается противопоставление)

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Имеется или подразумевается противопоставление с "не"5. Не удача привела спортсмена к победе, а упорные тренировки.
6. Самообладание не помеха, а залог успеха.
4. Это не ошибка.
5. Не удача привела спортсмена к победе, а упорные тренировки.
 

Слово без "не" не употребляется
2. Невежда - это неуч, мало знающий человек.
3. Невежа тот, кто позволяет себе грубость.

Слово с "не" можно заменить синонимом без "не"
1. Невезение преследовало меня.
7. Каждая неудача прибавляет ума.

Comment: Да. Правильно все.